# Using set as an default parameter of recursive method in Python

Tags: python

I wanted to do something like:

```
class foo():
    def __init__():
        ...
    def bar(self, param=set()):
        ...
```

where bar call itself using recursion, passing set. But after implementing following snippet my script started to do strange things. So I decided, that I will change it to the following form:

```
class foo():
    def __init__():
        ...
    def bar(self, param):
        if param is None:
            param=set()
```

After this change everything works as intended. Do anyone now, why the origin form does not work?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Not at all. From outside the object I call this function not using this parameter. Let's assume, that I want to check some properties of passed object. If I want to check some properties, from time to time I have to prove, that other property is owned by passed object. But I do not want to check previously checked properties, so I pass set of checked features, when I call bar inside bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documented thing, from [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

> Default parameter values are evaluated from left to right when the function definition is executed. This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used for each call. This is especially important to understand when a default parameter is a mutable object, such as a list or a dictionary: if the function modifies the object (e.g. by appending an item to a list), the default value is in effect modified. This is generally not what was intended. A way around this is to use None as the default, and explicitly test for it in the body of the function.

So, it says the second method, explicitly test for the parameters if None and then assign the empty set is the best way to avoid the problem.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you a lot. Actually there is nothing new to me in the quoted lines, but I wasn't thinking about this problem this way. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this is one of the places where Python really screwed up.  This feature catches everyone, even if you know about it.

Comment: @FrankYellin yeah you are right, but bright community always bring workarounds for us!